# How to handle "NA" in Julia

Tags: julia, missing-data

I need to hadle a file with missing values ("NA") in Julia.
The command that I'm using to read the file is:

`file = readdlm("FILE_NAs.txt", header=false)`

The problem is that I can't use this files in math equations (like matrix multiplication) because the "NA"s.
I tried to use the package "DataArray" and the function "dropna(file)", but did not work.
So, I'd like to ignore or even remove those "NA"s values.

Here is a sample of the loaded file (space delimited):

```
"Ind1" "NA"  "NA"  "NA"   "NA"   "NA"   "NA"  2   "NA"   "NA"
"Ind2" "NA"  "NA"  "NA"   "NA"   "NA"   "NA"  2   "NA"   "NA"
"Ind3" "NA"  "NA"  "NA"   "NA"   "NA"   "NA"  1   "NA"   "NA"
"Ind4" "NA"  "NA"  "NA"   "NA"   "NA"   "NA"  2   "NA"   "NA"
"Ind5" 0     0     0      0      0      0     1   0      0 
"Ind6" 1     0     0      0      1      1     2   1      1 
"Ind7" 1     0     0      0      1      1     2   1      1 
"Ind8" 0     0     0      0      0      0     2   0      0
```

Comment: are the NA quoted? can you give us a snippet of your data file and a minimal working example? could you load it as a delimited file or `DataFrame` and then simply subset against the "NA" strings?

Comment: Yes, I could use another function to load the file. To be honest, I have tried another functions to load the file, but then I couldn't handle the file as I do with this function (readdlm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NA` type is explicitly designed to poison linear algebra operations, so you should not be multiplying arrays with `NA` in them.

I am assuming that you load the data with something like

```
using DataFrames
x = readtable("FILE_NAs.txt", header = false, separator = ' ')
```

If you merely want to purge the rows containing `NA`, then the *easiest* thing to do is probably to call

```
y = DataFrames.na_omit(x)[1]
```

That will yield a new `DataFrame` where any row containing `NA` has been purged. If you want to extract the numeric data from your example file, then something like

```
z = convert(Matrix{Int}, y[2:end])
```

should work. We can index `y` like a vector because a `DataFrame` behaves like a vector of columnar `DataArray`s. Note that the conversion of a `DataFrame` with `NA` entries to a `Matrix` will [fail](http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

If instead you want to purge by column, then determine which columns have `NA` in them. One way to do this is via

```
# get a Bool array of NA positions
y = array(map(isna, eachcol(x)))

# get a vector indexing columns with NA in them
z = vec(!reducedim(|, y, 1))

# now extract columns of x with no missing data
x[z] # <-- only has rows x1, x8
```

`DataFrame` gurus may know a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Hi.    That could be a option if there is someway to convert this file withou NAs in an Array or Matrix.    Using `readtable` I'm not able to use the rest of my script that contains funcitions like `findin`, like: `tmp = file[findin(file, file2[:,1]), :]`    . Is it possible?    Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand what that code does. does `findin` require indexing? note that a `DataArray` object -- and by extension a `DataFrame` -- require [careful indexing](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataArrays.jl/issues/207) since NA poisons that operation too. as for converting to a `Matrix`, see edited response.

Comment: Still not working :/ . I beliave that the command `DataFrames.na_omit(x)[1]` is not working properly because `x` has dimension of `30×49620` and `y` has `0×49620`.

Comment: the command merely prunes all rows with missing data. clearly this means that every one of your rows contains at least one `NA`. ;-)

Comment: see update for code to purge columns with `NA` in them